# php if não funciona quando não tem nada declarado pela url

Tags: php, if

Estou com esse erro na variável coloquei para mostrar o código somente quando tiver a referencia. mas da erro quando não tem nada declarado.

Ou seja, quando acesso o site com site.com/?ref=app (da certo), porem quando acesso sem, ele da o erro abaixo.

**Erro quando não tem nada definido na URL:**

```
Warning: Undefined array key "ref" in \header.php on line 1
```

**Meu codigo atual:**

```html
<?php if ($_GET["ref"] == "app") : ?>
  <style media="screen">
    #sidebar {
      display: none !important;
    }

    .navbar {
      display: none !important;
    }
  </style>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Opa amigo. Acredito que está faltando o `else`. já testou?

```
(condition ? action_if_true: action_if_false;)
```

Pelo q eu entendi do teu código, ele ta verificando se vêm o "`($_GET["ref"] == "app")`". No caso quando vc coloca direto na url ele vai, mas se vc não coloca, está caindo no `else` o que faz com que não aconteça nada.

Answer (score 0):

Cara, estou tentando aprender PHP. Estou correndo o risco de estar errado.
Mas acho que seu problema pode ser resolvido com *isset*.

https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.isset

Penso que talvez nem precise usar o *if else* porque o *isset* se comporta como tal. Usando o isset você pode verificar se o parâmetro enviado pela url foi definida. Então ficaria algo assim:

```
<?php 
        $ref = isset($_GET["ref"])?$_GET["ref"]:0;
        print $ref; // para testar o parametro recebido da url
        #seu codigo...
    ?>
```